# WCF - There was no endpoint listening at [URL] that could accept the message C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm experimenting a very weird behavior. I have hosted successfully a WCF Service; I'm referencing the service in a client application using service references in the following manner:

```
string res = "";
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("http://myhosting/Service.svc");
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(binding, epa);
res = client.GetMyService(<parameters>);
client.Close();
```

When I run my client application in debug mode, it successfully connect and retrieve information from the service, but, if I run the application without debugging or in Release mode, it throws the exception: **"There was no endpoint listening at [URL] that could accept the message"**. It also happens when I try to run the application directly from the bin/[debug/release] folder generated from compilation.

I have no idea why is this happening.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your service definitely running?  It could be that if you have the service and client in the same solution, when you start in debug mode it will host the service locally for you - but of course that wouldn't be the case in release mode.

Comment: Try entering "http://myhosting/Service.svc" into your web browser to see if the service is actually running

Comment: Of course, the service is hosted and working properly, when I reference the IIS host via Service references: I type: http://myhost/Service.svc?wsdl and is retrieved successfully

Comment: @Hahn - Is it `myhost/Service.svc` or `myhosting/Service.svc`?  Are you sure the address you're using in the code is the right one?

Comment: Yes, as I said, it works fine while I run the application in Debug mode. The issue arises when I change from "Debug" mode to "Release". If I compile the code, and I run it from the bin file generated it also throws the error. I don't know if VS is doing something I'm missing...